# Store list of ids and check it exist there or not

Tags: list, search

I have some id which i am getting from database matching some criteria specified there.
No of id may be 100.
I will store all that id at somewhere at loading of application.
I have one continuos running process which return id and i want to check that returned id is exist in stored IDS.
So how can i check it.I am thinking about some samrt way to do it.Otherwise i can check it with Loop.
I don't want to check that using my sql query because it needs server connection at that time.
In C# how can i  check weather stored id is exist there or not and Which type of variable should i use to store all ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do, but if you're trying to see which ids from a list still exist, you can do so via SQL. If your list of ids contains "2,3,5,7", you can check to see which of those still exists via:

```
select id from my_table where id in (2,3,5,7)
```

Or, if you're receiving an id from the user and you want to check whether it exists within a disconnected list of ids, use your ids as keys in a [`Dictionary<int, int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx). You can check whether an id exists with a simple call to [`ContainsKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4.aspx) which will execute much faster than the loop you mentioned.